# successfully encode hex to bytes, but failed to transform bytes back to string-===>hex ->bytes; and bytes->string

Tags: python, hash

given hex, and formed bytes

looking for bytes to string

---

```
def hex_to_b:
    return bytes.fromhex('abc')
#now you have a byte type string
#looking to decode back to the string

#failure of transformation
hex_to_b().decode(encoding="utf-8",errors="strict")
```

Comment: `'abc'` is not a valid hex string.

Answer (score 1):

To convert bytes to hex, and the other way round, use built-in `binascii` module.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html

Example:

```
>>> from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify
>>> unhexlify('deadbeef')
b'\xde\xad\xbe\xef'
>>> hexlify(b'\xde\xad\xbe\xef').decode()
'deadbeef'
```

Make sure a valid hex-string is passed.